# Who is Joy Boy?

Tags: one-piece

I just finished the "Fishman Island" arc and there are some unexplained things like, who is Joy Boy? Is Joy Boy the one who wrote all the poneglyph?

Comment: Too many questions in just one post. Please consider keeping only the closely related questions in this post, and split up the rest to another post.

Comment: Also consider keeping only the questions that actually can be answered, and not only speculated

Comment: Speculation in answers is fine as long as canonical sources can be cited to support your answer. Blind speculations without citations are no more than baseless headcanon.

Comment: I'll take a chance to salvage this question. However, I don't know if this question can be answered without too much speculation as per previous comments since reading [Joy Boy's article on Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Joy_Boy) doesn't look so promising... though maybe there's non-English resource that might explain this.

Comment: "Unexplained" in One Piece can be translated as "Not Yet Explained" so, keep watching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joy Boy was a man from the surface world who made the promise with the people of Fishman Island. He tried to raise the Noah with the help of Poseidon but he broke his promise. On Poneglyph, he wrote an apology to Poseidon. That's the only info available about Joy Boy.